# Alter Table giving fatal Error in Mysql

Tags: mysql

While Altering a table in mysql to Add a new Column I am getting Fatal Error Occurred.. I ve seen the relevant answers for this question where I found an Answer like :--

```
Make a new table with the same structure.
Add the column to the new table.
Insert the data from the old table into the new table.
Rename the old table to old.bak
Rename the new table to the old table.
If all went well, delete the old.bak.
```

But my original table contains some triggers , indexes, etc.

My question is

*"Can I write my Alter Script in any diff. way to overcome this fatal Error" ?*

My concern is related to MYSQL, but any other RDBMS related answers also fine...

Comment: I am using the alter table syntax as :--"ALTER TABLE table_name Add column_name datatype(size)"

Comment: What is the syntax of new Column Addition that you are using?

Comment: what is the DataType ur using?

Comment: Normal Alter table syntax :-- "ALTER TABLE table_name Add column_name datatype(size)"

Comment: the datatype of the column is a varchar and my table contain almost 2million data

Comment: If you really use `datatype(size)` as quoted, this won't work. You have to put something real, like `VARCHAR(20)`

Comment: Please add table structure and the exact Sql command and the full error message. I have done this plenty  of times. You just don't have enough detail in your question.

Comment: alter table student add fname varchar(100)-- here i ve changed my table name and column name.But my syntax is of this type and I am getting 'File Fatal error encountered for following scripts'.

Comment: Is there no more detail in the error message? In which application are you running the SQL statement? We need to see the exact error message all of it.

Comment: Agree with Namphibian here, this should work with an ALTER TABLE statement. Much preferable to the slinky-copy maneuver.

Answer (score 0):

This is MySQL specific: You can use a combination of `[SHOW CREATE TABLE tabname][1]` and `[SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE Table = 'tabname'][2]` to regenerate the table and triggers. You probably don't want the triggers firing when you are copying the rows. Also, if the table is of a significant size or you have a high enough rate of change, you probably want to prevent writes to it during the copy.

Sequence of steps:

1. Prevent writes to table (optional)
2. Create new table with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output.
3. Apply schema changes.
4. Copy data from old table to new table.
5. Apply triggers from `SHOW TRIGGERS` output.
6. Swap old and new tables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Appreciate the Answer,but is this the only way to solve these type of fatal Errors.Means I have to definitely create a back up table and then alter... If any other alternative is there it ll be good.Thanks for the answers and comments.